# Consequences of the Halting Problem

Tags: turing-machines, halting-problem, nondeterminism, semi-decidability, termination

The halting problem is **semi-decidable**.
Does that mean that:

- If a program *terminates* it can always be established/determined?
- If a program does *not terminate*

  - It can sometimes be established/determined?
  - It can sometimes not be established/determined?

When we write programs we can clearly proof in some instances that the program terminates or that it will never terminate.
But, simply there are some programs for which we can't proof termination for all inputs.

Comment: A simple strategy is to run the program. If it halts before one year, you are done. Otherwise, say that you don't know.

Comment: Since for all programs with a set of possible inputs which is countably infinite [except 0-arry functions i.e. constant functions], it would not be possible even to run the program until it terminates for all inputs.

Answer (score 2):

The Halting Problem is semi-decidable, also called recognizable, and that means there is a Turing Machine $H$ that will, given a Turing Machine $M$ as input, accept $\langle M, s\rangle$ if and only if it halts in finite time on bounded input $s$ and otherwise will reject or fail to halt itself. This means, in a certain sense, that a TM that halts in finite time on an input $s$ can always be recognized as such.

However, there is no upper bound on how long $H$ can run for an arbitrary input $\langle M, s\rangle$. This means the results of $H$ are useful only for establishing that certain machines halt, but never for establishing that other machines *don't* halt – after all, even after running $H(\langle M, s\rangle)$ for arbitrarily long we cannot say with certainty whether $M$ does not halt on $s$, or whether $H(\langle M, s\rangle)$ just needs more time to compute. Therefore we cannot, with perfect certainty, know which TMs halt and which ones don't – but fixing a string $s$ and running $H$ on different TMs will give us a set of TMs that certainly halt on $s$ that grows the more time $H$ is given.

There is no general procedure for recognizing non-halting TMs: any putative non-halting recognizer will fail to recognize some subset of non-halting TMs as non-halting. However, there are partial recognizers for non-halting: this is the simplest to see with restricted cases of TM. For instance a TM that moves right with every state transition can be determined to never halt if it visits the same state twice after reading to the right of its input.

Answer (score 0):

I think you are right.

If a program terminates, it can always be determined by running the universal TM to simulate the program trivially.
If a program does not terminate, it can be determined sometimes by recognizing some special structures like infinite loop; or cannot be determined when the input is something in the part that causes HALT to be undecidable.

Comment: "If a program terminates, it can always be determined by running the universal TM to simulate the program trivially": this does not work because you don't know how long you have to wait.

Comment: It’s not that case. A decider only needs to know that it *will* halt eventually, with no need on guaranteeing its running time.

Comment: You contradict yourself. Running the program does not tell you that it will terminate.

Comment: Please read the condition again... The original problem description says, **"If the program terminates**, it can always be determined", which just means that the algorithm **only** need to have correct behavior on these specified-to-terminate inputs (rather than **all** inputs).

Comment: I see. The condition can be understood as "If the program is a terminating one [for this input]". Hence the confusion. If the program under scrutiny indeed terminates, I can't see why you would still need to "determine" and "simulate" anything. This strengthens the confusion.

Comment: @YvesDaoust perhaps consider it as a [certificate](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Certificate_(complexity)) - every program which halts can be proven to halt, and the proof is simply how long you have to wait before it halts, then you can simulate it yourself and see. But if a program doesn't halt, I can't necessarily prove to you that it doesn't.

Comment: My point is that your text is ambiguous.